# HttpClient MultipartRequest Connection Refused

Tags: java, rest, multipartform-data

I have 2 applications which need to send files to each other using HttpClient libraries:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the code to send the file:

```
    private static void executeRequest(HttpPost httpPost, String url) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println("Response Code:  " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void executeMultiPartRequest(String urlString, File file) throws IOException {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlString);
        postRequest = addHeader(postRequest, "Access Token");

        try {
            HttpEntity fileEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), file.getName()).build();
            postRequest.setEntity(fileEntity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        executeRequest(postRequest, urlString);
    }


    private static HttpPost addHeader(HttpPost httpPost, String accessToken) {
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        return httpPost;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path = "/send", produces = {MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public void send() throws IOException {
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:2990/asanrest/1.0/receiveFile";
        File file = new File("server-info.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        executeMultiPartRequest(url, file);
    }
```

This works on my local machine, applications send the file to each other successfully. However, when I upload one of the applications to the server, then I can send the file from local machine to the server, but when sending from the server back to the local machine, I get the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at com.softgile.asan.asanservice.rest.AsanRestController.executeRequest(AsanRestController.java:350)
        at com.softgile.asan.asanservice.rest.AsanRestController.executeMultiPartRequest(AsanRestController.java:373)
        at com.softgile.asan.asanservice.rest.AsanRestController.send(AsanRestController.java:389)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the problem here? Isn't it possible to send the file from the server back to local machine? Is there a problem with the url? I have tried to use

```
http://localhost:2990

http://127.0.0.1:2990

192.168.x.x. - local IP address
```

Nothing works. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between two servers, please use local ip address to connect, and not use 127.0.0.1

> please use local machine ip address instead of 127.0.0.1

```
String url = "http://192.168.x.x:2990/asanrest/1.0/receiveFile";
```

For network trouble shooting, please refer this one. https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/internet-and-networking/troubleshooting-network-applications-with-curl

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I have tried this method too. This method returns "connection timed out".

Comment: So this is a network problem and you code is ok. You can use another server machine to test. And In my opinion, we need not test it, from server a to b is ok, from server b to a is obviously ok, and I advice you to configure url in a config file.

Comment: I still cannot understand the problem. I have tried to troubleshoot the problem with the URL above:

Comment: How about ping local machine from server, what is the result?

Comment: Good idea, so when pinging from local to the server, it successfully goes, and otherwise is failing. Is there a way to get it work somehow? Is it related to some network security or what?

Comment: Yes, maybe for security, firewall setting and other security setting can forbid it.